# Wearing Tallis/Tzitzit at night

Tags: halacha, clothing, chazzan-prayer-leader, tallit-gadol, evening-night

I have read in Rabbi Hertzel Hillel Yitzchak's book Tzel Heharim: Tzitzit that it is permissable for a chazzan to wear a tallis at night (see page 60 of that book) provided that he does not have an outer garment over his shirt. He does give some references for saying this but these (Halachah Berura Vol 1 18.3 and Tzitzit halacha pesukah 18.11) are unclear/unknown to me. can someone expand on the basis for permitting a chazzan to wear a tallis at night. Thanks

Comment: Why would he not be allowed to wear a tallis at night?

Comment: the rambam says that a person must wear a 6aleeth for every tafillo. teimonim wear a 6aleeth for every tafillo. we however say the barocho at meen7o and wear it until after 3arabeeth. or just put it on without a barocho for 3arabeeth

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob 6aaleeth ka++on doesn't count?

Comment: @user6591 i dont wear such a thing for its not a baghadh. mori qafi7 talks about this. it would be considered carrying on shabboth if you wear it

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps because the mitzvah of tzitzit is for during the day.

Comment: @scimonster just because we are not obligated doesn't mean we are forbidden. Do we need a justification for not taking off our tallis katan immediately at nightfall?

Comment: @Daniel I don't disagree with you; I was just giving my interpretation of the OP's concern.

Answer (score 3):

A chazzan does not wear the talis to be yotzeh the mitzvah of tzitzis. He only wears it to have an atiffa, for kavod hatzibur. 
This is the same reason he doesn't make a bracha on it when he puts it on.

Comment: What about the night of Yom Kippur when everyone wears a tallit - not just the chazzan?

Comment: @DanF that is different. We do want to be wearing the taalis for a mitzvah then which is why we make sure to put it on during the day so we can make a bracha.

Comment: @DanF There is an interesting stira in the Aruch Hashulchan which has a little to do with this subject. In hilchos tzitzis and in hilchos yom kippur he discusses whether wearing a talis on Yom kippur night is called normal, and therefore it is muttar to wear outside or it is not normal because no other night is it worn and it would be carrying. In one place he rules one way and in the other place he rules the opposite way.

Comment: I guess this is a situation where the Shulchan is not completely "aruch" (arranged / set) :-)

Comment: @DanF I guess you couldn't resist that 'set up':)

Comment: @user6591 I think it's a machloket rambam vs rif in general about wearing tzitzit out on friday night